# Magento 1.9 - Sending Shipment email to customer but without Packing Slip

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shipment

i would ask how send shipment email to customer, when the order status change in backend, without the attached of Packing Slip. Where can i go for not include packing slip in shipment email?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by modifying the email template from the Magento admin.
From the dashboard,

1. Go to System > Transactional Emails
2. Click on Add New Template
3. Under Template, Select "New Shipment", set locale and Load Template
4. Enter a new template name
5. Edit the template - This is where you remove anything you don't want to be sent in the email or add new things.
6. Save the new Template.
7. Go to System > Configuration > Sales Emails > Shipment
8. Set shipment Email Template to the new template you created and Save.

Do the same for Guest Shipment Emails if you allow guest checkout.

Comment: Thanks man for the answer. I tried to visit this section but i have not found method for not sending packing slip pdf with shipment email...other possible solutions?

Comment: Hi!!! I Found the solution!!! In short, my template for shipment email is connected to the app Easy PDF for Magento. I went configuration of this app and I have configured "no" in the "Attach the Shipment PDF to Shipment Email ". Thanks for the help that has led me to the solution , which was just on the back end. ; )

Comment: Happy to Help :)